# getUserMedia to get video stream, galaxy S20 screen's aspect ratio broken

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, video-streaming, html5-video, getusermedia

[problem screen shot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmPuE.jpg)
[normal screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cibQ.jpg)

Specific device(Galaxy S20 with chrome browser), shows the video stream like the image above.

Almost all of devices are fine, but some devices have the problems like this.

How can I approach the problem?

How can I solve it?

my code for getting the Stream data,

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getStreamData = async () => {
      if (videoRef.current) {
        try {
          const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: {
              aspectRatio: 3 / 4,
              facingMode: 'environment',
            },
          });
          window.stream = stream;
          videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error getStreamData', error);
        }
      }
    };
    getStreamData();

    return () => {
      cameraOff();
    };
  }, []);
```

my code for styled component

```
<RootContainer>
  <Dummy />
  <ScanContainer>
    <StyledVideo playsInline autoPlay controls ref={videoRef}>
      VideoStream Not Available.
    </StyledVideo>
    <StyledCanvas width={1280} height={720} ref={canvasRef} />
  </ScanContainer>
</RootContainer>
```

```
const RootContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #363636;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-color: #001b45 !important;
`;

const ScanContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
`;

const StyledVideo = styled.video`
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
`;

const StyledCanvas = styled.canvas`
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  border: 3px solid silver;
`;

const Dummy = styled.div`
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 90%;
`;
```

thank you for your help

I tried changing aspect ratio to 9:16,
using width/height instead of aspectRatio in getUserMedia constraint.

crop also have some problem with latest chrome.
cuz it can not get the offset value.

Comment: The constraints you pass to `getUserMedia()` aren't really constraints. Rather they're hints. Your device's implementation tries its best to give you what you requested. It looks like this device doesn't know how to do four thirds for an aspect ratio, and is giving 16:9 instead. It's a well known pain in the neck with WebRTC media.

Comment: thank you for your comments. so what could I do for it not to be broken? I really have a hard time with this... do you have any idea?